# Need with loop when reading from text files

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL so bear with me, so my project requires me to read in bytes of data from a text file, for example, 7076 bytes from a text file containing `AA BB CC` and so on in many lines. I am required to read it with a clock cycle.

The problem when using a while loop while (inline'length /= 0)  loop, the loop reads the data as intended however once it reaches the last byte of data the while loop ends skipping reading it. So.. reads up to the 7075 byte before ending.

I tried changing the while (inline'length >= 0)  loop however it ends on the first line of data which is as expected. I was thinking of implementing an array but I am unsure how would I set it up in this case.

```
file     infile    : text is in  "textfile.txt";   --declare input file
variable inline    : line; --line number declaration

---------------program-----------------------
begin
  while not endfile(infile) loop   --checking the "END OF FILE" is not reached.

  readline(infile, inline);       --reading a line from the file.

  while (inline'length /= 0)  loop 
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    hread(inline, inputdata);

    readdatainput <= inputdata;

  end loop;
```

On the first clock cycle the data reads in as expected and continues on all the way till the 7075 cycle. However there is 7076 bytes of data.

Looking for any ways to solve this problem or ideas on solutions.

Comment: why not do the read before the clock edge?

Comment: Hey thanks! I shifted the wait until rising_edge to below both hread and readdatainput output statement and it seems like it is able to read until the last byte of data. This seems like quite a simple mistake I made.

Comment: It was reading it just fine, but because you assigned it after the clock edge it may appeared like it was not being applied to the input depending on when the simulation ended.